# Cannot assign JSON response to a pre-declared array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, moya

I'm working on a hobby project iOS app in Swift to learn using JSON with Moya. Here is how my VC code looks like:

```
import UIKit
import Moya
import Moya_ModelMapper

class SQSquirrelListViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

  var squirrels: [Squirrel] = []

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.fetchData()
  }


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
  }

  func fetchData() {
    let provider = MoyaProvider<SQService>()
    provider.request(.squirrelsIndex(page: "1")) { result in
      switch result {
      case let .success(moyaResponse):
        do {
          let sq = try moyaResponse.mapObject() as Squirrels
          self.squirrels = sq.items
        } catch {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        let statusCode = moyaResponse.statusCode
        print("STATUS CODE: \(statusCode)")
      case let .failure(error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

After launching the app the `squirrels` array is empty. I'm not sure whether it's related to Moya or is it a flaw in the flow of my View Controller?

Comment: Is anything printed in the console?

Comment: @hybridcattt Only the status code, as in the print statement inside fetchData(). The array is empty in the debugger, also throws "array index out of bounds" when I try to use squirrels[indexPath.row] in the table view's datasource methods.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint to `self.squirrels = sq.items` and see what's in `sq`. Also print `try moyaResponse.mapObject()` - that's very likely empty.

Comment: @hybridcattt printing `self.squirrels` returned proper values. The issue was in what @vadian pointed out - moving `self.tableView.reloadData()` inside the completion handler fixed the issue.

Comment: @vadian - please respond so I can accept your answer. Thank you both for involvement and helping me learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line to reload the table view must be **inside** the completion handler.